# Switch language in Rattle (R package) after installation

Tags: r, rattle

How do I switch the language of Rattle after installation via install.packages("rattle")?

I dont find any "Settings" Tab or similar. I have RStudio installed in english, but after I ran the above command, Rattle installed itself in German (which is my locale) but i want to use it in English.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Quit Rattle -> run Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en") -> restart rattle again

Its english now.

Love